# Create in Python a new file with the common matches on two dataframes

Tags: python, import, match, extract

dataset2.csv needs to find matches on the first column on dataset1.csv, the output.csv needs to have only the matches and some attributes. 
The first column is a string.

```
Dataset1.csv
Name   age
John   2
Peter  1
Sara   3
```

```
Dataset2.csv
Name   city    Time
John   NY, NY  3:10AM
Peter  LA, CA  7:45PM
```

```
Output.csv
Name   age city    Time
John   2   NY, NY  3:10AM
Peter  1   LA, CA  7:45PM
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = np.loadtxt('Dataset1.csv')

df2 = np.loadtxt('Dataset2.csv')


df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['name','age'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2,columns=['name','city','Time'])

print(df1)
print(df2)
intersected_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
print(intersected_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `np.loadtxt` for reading, instead use the `pandas` `read_csv` function, and also have a `on` argument and specify the column, in this case `Name`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('Dataset1.csv', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Dataset2.csv', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
intersected_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name')
print(intersected_df)
```

Output:

```
    Name  age    city    Time
0   John    2  NY, NY  3:10AM
1  Peter    1  LA, CA  7:45PM
```